# What does the "wi" stand for in SQL Azure Automatic Index Naming?

Tags: sql-server, index, naming-convention

I have a SQL Database on Azure that is giving me a performance recommendation for an index.

What does the "wi" part of the name?  I'm guessing something to do with the include part of the statement.  With Include?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_TableName_468BA2FCEC4455FB9A6ACA94430E4935] ON [dbo].[TableName] ([Id]) INCLUDE ([ColA], [ColB]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my memory isn't *completely* gone, it means "worker insights". Not sure if this was in a blog post or a Channel 9 video. It'll probably take a bit to find the source.

Or maybe "workload increase" — one of the [detectable performance patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/intelligent-insights-troubleshoot-performance#workload-increase) that might call for a new index recommendation.

Why does the name matter? If you choose to implement the recommendation, you can change it according to your organization's standards.

"Workload Insight" was the internal name for the auto-indexing feature.  There's typically one name that a product, feature, or release has during development, before the marketing people help choose the official name.

Comment: "Workload Insight" was the internal name for the auto-indexing feature.  There's typically one name that a product, feature, or release has during development, before the marketing people help choose the official name.